# NLS_LANG and NLS_CHARACTERSET

Tags: oracle, encoding

I thought I read that `NLS_CHARACTERSET` has the encoding of the database and `NLS_LANG` the encoding of the client. Is that correct?

Does that mean that the two encodings can be different?

In some other documentations, I read that the `NLS_LANG` is defined by the `NLS_CHARACTERSET`. Which assertion is true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NLS parameters can be quite tedious to understand and I recommend searching for the term "Setting Up a Globalization Support Environment" in the official documentation.

NLS is short for National Language Support and is the beginning of multiple parameters that are available in the various Oracle products.

---

## NLS_LANG

`NLS_LANG` is described as a variable that defines the `<LANGUAGE>_<TERRITORY>.<CHARACTER_SET>` of your client environment.

An example of a valid NLS_LANG setting would be:

```
NLS_LANG=AMERCICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCII
```

#### Language

The individual parts of the variable define how Oracle displays information. If your `<LANGUAGE>` is `AMERICAN` then messages, days and months will be displayed using American spelling. Sorting is also affected by this part of the parameter

#### Territory

Territory affects things like the default date, settings for money values (e.g. `$` sign), and number formats (e.g. `3,000,000.12` to display three million point 12)

#### Character_Set

This is the bit where it becomes pretty interesting. This part of the NLS_LANG parameter is described as the

> ...character set used by the client application.

### Summary NLS_LANG

So in essence you are configuring how you client would display data stored in the database. If your database contains the following data:

```
 Employee     | Employment Start    | Salary
--------------+---------------------+--------
 Michael Ward | 2018-01-01          | 100240
```

...then if your client has `AMERICAN_AMERICA.US7ASCI` as the `NLS_LANG` setting, then querying this table would return:

```
 Employee     | Employment Start     | Salary
--------------+----------------------+-------------
 Michael Ward | 01-JAN-18            | 100,240
```

...whereas having a setting of `FRENCH_FRANCE.WE8ISO8859P1` would result in:

```
 Employee     | Employment Start     | Salary
--------------+----------------------+-------------
 Michael Ward | 01/01/18             | 100'240
```

Lets follow up with the other parameter...

---

## NLS_CHARACTERSET

The `NLS_CHARACTERSET` parameter is setup during the creation of your database instance and shouldn't be changed thereafter. (It can be altered but it can cause data corruption even in the DATA DICTIONARY objects). This parameter defines the encoding of the data in the ...

#### NLS_CHARACTERSET Parameter

... `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, `LONG` and `CLOB` columns of a table.

#### NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET Parameter

... `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR2` and `NCLOB` columns of a table.

### Summary NLS_CHARACTERSET

The parameter is used to tell the RDBMS system with which encoding it shold store data in certain columns.

*I have intentionally left a large portion of the explanation regarding `NLS_CHARACTERSET` out, because it gets really complicated when comparing encodings between `AL8UTF8`, `AL32UTF8` and `AL16UTF16` (which can only be use in conjunction with the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` parameter) and all the other possible Unicode settings.*

---

## Comparison

When retrieving data from a database column `NLS_LANG` will add all the bells and whistles (date formatting, time formatting, number formatting) to the data that is being retrieved.

The `NLS_CHARACTERSET` parameter defines with which encoding the data is stored in the columns. (ASCII, Unicode, ...)

## Answering your Question

> Does that mean that the two encodings can be different?

Yes, you can have two totally different encodings. You could store you data using a setting of `NLS_CHARACTERSET = AL32UTF8` and still display and transport the data to the database with `NLS_LANG=American_America.US7ASCII`.

> Display vs. Storage

Comment: You can change the database Characters set, however it is not a single `ALTER DATABASE ...` command, see [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011)

Answer (score 0):

They can be different. The short explanation is that the characters are stored in the database as defined by the `NLS_CHARACTERSET`. If the client is not able to use this character-set. The `NLS_LANG` also holds region. If the client uses a different currency, date format, decimal point/comma as is expected by the database then this can also differ.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumptions are right (see other answer)

> Does that mean that the two encodings can be different?

Yes, in fact they are **always** different if you consider that your database has **two** character sets, the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` and the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` and you may use both in one single statement.

`NLS_CHARACTERSET` and `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` are typically different. Thus `NLS_LANG`is either different to `NLS_CHARACTERSET` or different to `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`.

You find some useful information at [NLS_LANG FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html)

> In some other documentations, I read that the `NLS_LANG` is defined by
>   the `NLS_CHARACTERSET`. Which assertion is true?

This statement seems to be wrong. However, my impression is that `TOAD` first opens a DB connections, reads the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` value and then open the "final" DB connection where `NLS_LANG` is set according to previously read `NLS_CHARACTERSET`. But this seems to be a rather sophisticated approach of doing it.